# C#, Select by tag

Tags: winforms

I'm new with c# and am wanting to set all panels to visible=false that share the same tag. This will prevent me from calling each panel name individually and setting it to false when activating a new panel.

Any help?

This is how I would do it the old way:

```
private void button3click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Panel1.Visible = false;
 Panel2.Visible = false
 Panel3.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using Windows Forms? Windows Forms controls do not have tags like controls did in VB6.

Comment: Hey John, I'm using Microsoft Visual c# Express 2010. I'm not exactly sure what their tagging system is for, but I'm hoping it can act as a selectable. Here's a screen shot of the area I set the tag parameter http://screencast.com/t/TwjTU1E6RYcy

Comment: I thought they had gotten rid of tags, but I guess keep them around for backwards compatability. I still don't see how those would help you. It's not possible to easily find all the controls with a given tag. You'd really be better off just using each control. It will make your code cleaner, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sets of controls that you frequently refer to as a group, then you can try to place those controls into a list:

```
List<Control> typeAControls = new List<Control>(){control1, control2};
List<Control> typeBControls = new List<Control>(){control3, control4};

foreach (var toHide in typeAControls)
{
    toHide.Visible = false;
}

foreach (var toHide in typeBControls)
{
    toHide.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, useful!

When setting controls, can I setup a global control or will I have to define them within every function? I'm still learning about how to operate namespaces and classes. And also, are controls in the new control list the AccessibleNames of my panels?

Comment: No, those are the class members which reference the controls themselves. I think I might suggest that you not get too far ahead of the class. Techniques like this are only occasionally of use. To see what those names are that I used, click the word "Panel1" in "Panel1.Visible=false;" then right-click and choose "Go to definition".